# How do I create a hstore column in a Sequel migration?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, migration, sequel, hstore

How do I create a hstore column in a Sequel migration?

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    add_column :logs, :geo, HStore
  end
end
```

fails. Do I have to load an extension?

Comment: I suspect your answer lies in this documentation, http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/postgresql_rdoc.html. Specifically, look at the heading **PostgreSQL-specific Database Type Support**

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the correct doc page, but I still can't run the migration. I tried different names like :hstore, :h_store, :pg_hstore, HStore, etc. I've loaded the :pg_store DB extension and even added sequel_pg & sequel-hstore gems to the Gemfile. Tried with json datatype and works ok, but I prefer hstore.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in the gem. Have you reported it to the maintainers?

Comment: I'll look in the [G.Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sequel-talk), thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Author's gem answered me](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sequel-talk/U08ycT0fgMI/g2RuvUhK6qAJ), the DB needs this additional extension before using it:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore
```

Comment: BTW, the correct line is   add_column :logs, :geo, :hstore # or 'hstore'

Answer (score 4):

I could not find this in the documentation so I asked on IRC.

> jeremyevans: method_missing is used, allowing you to use any custom database types

So you can specify `json`, `jsonb` as long as the extension is enabled:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table :foo do
      primary_key :id
      jsonb :bar
    end
  end
end
```

To enable the extension:

```
Sequel.extension :pg_json
```

And to create a new record:

```
foo = Foo.new bar: Sequel.pg_jsonb({ 'baz' => 'qux' })
```